# format textview in Listview

Tags: android, listview, textview, strikethrough

I have a ListView with some items. I'd like to set ListView where some items are strikethrough. I know how to make it using onclicklistener, but I'd like to load ListView with already marked strikethrough items.

So I start up my programm and an effect should be something like this:

first /strikethrough/

second

third

fourth /strikethrough/

Comment: Are you asking how to make text strikethrough, or how to customize your listview?

Comment: I'm asking how to customize my listview, I know how to make text strikethrough

Answer (score 1):

To customize your list view you probably need to make a Custom ListView ArrayAdapter which will load your text view and set it to strikethrough:

```
private class ResultsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Route> {

    private ArrayList<Route> items;

    public ResultsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Route> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.route_row, null);
        }
        Route res = items.get(position);
        if (res != null) {
            TextView line1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.route_line1);
//setup your strikethrough as needed.

            }

        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading data from a SimpleAdapter, override the SimpleAdapter.setViewBinder method. This method is used when you execute ListView.SetAdapter(SimpleAdapter) to fill your Listview with data from the SimpleAdapter. Override this method to strikethrough your needed rows, but make sure to include the following lines of code:

```
TextView tv=(TextView) aView;
tv.setText(aCursor.getString(aColumnIndex));
```

These are to ensure that your listview items text appear.

Comment: I can add DbAdapter db, but I cannot add db = new DbAdapter(this), ERROR The constructor DbAdapter(MyCustomAdapter) is undefined.           this.db = (DbAdapter) context in constructor of MyCustomAdapter didnt solve my problem. I have to have access to my database

Comment: Can you share the code that you use to load the data to the ListView

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zV6Ysm31 erorr when call db.read_lista_produkty_array(id_listy, id_sklepu) -> java.lang.NullPointerException. Normally this function is working very well. Problem is causing by DbAdapter -> db = new DbAdapter(this.context); something wrong with context, hope you can help.

Comment: Can you try replacing `this.context` with `getApplicationContext()` or `this`

Comment: I've tried with no result, I've solved my problem by add one more argument to class constructor. Now not need to make object of class DbAdapter.